# Linux file system for a big file server

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I would like to know, from more experienced people, what would be the best choice of file system to use for a file server having more than 20TB of hard disks.
Personally I always used EXT3 (back in the days) and EXT4 (since available) [and once ReiserFS 3 though it caused many data corruption] on my personal computers and on the "little servers" BOOT and ROOT disks.

However as EXT4 **tools** (though not EXT4 itself) is limited to 16TB partitions this may not be my best bet.
Distribution will be Debian 6.0 (Squeeze) and / or Gentoo (latest version), so kernel should be pretty recent (on Debian at least with backports), meaning linux kernel >= 2.6.32.

File server will be used for maily three purposes (and separated partitions as well, because the purpose is to keep data "safe" and don't really care much of overhead).
**All disks are though to be encrypted using LUKS**:

1. Media, downloads and local debian repository [I have at least 6 machines running Debian] >20TB (maybe further separation between Media, Downloads and Debian repository)
2. Data (Documents, Photos, ...) ~ 4TB SAFE (meaning raid1 or raid6 + backup disk)
3. Backups >= 20 TB for backups of other computers in my gigabit lan (can you suggest a software that backups the entire OS even if it's windows, BackupPC says it does that, any alternatives ?)

Fast speeds are not really necessary (concurrent accesses: maximum to 2 or 3 large files, say videos), even if it's "just" 200MB/s reads from a 10 HDD Raid6 I can live with that.

In summary I look for a reliable, scalable (i.e. easily expandable) filesystem that supports more than 20TB / partition. The safer and reliable the FS is, the better. Hardware employed will be at least a quad core (amd x4 630 or intel i5-2500k) and plenty of RAM (>8GB, maybe >16GB) so hardware requirements should be met.

**My PCs / Server will be connected to an UPS (Uninterrupted Power Supply) in case of power outage**
Might do media and backups on separate machines as well (i.e. two servers).

Comment: At this scale,  you really need to be seriously evaluating ZFS. Rebuild times and error rates become serious concerns with as many discs as you're talking about and zfs is the only stable fs available now with robust error checking and correction all the way through the stack.

Comment: ZFS is not linux natively supported (only with FUSE) or is natively supported in an early pre-alpha state. I don't consider using solaris an option. Never tried FreeBSD once and may be interested, however I don't now if its software raid support (and general hardware support) is as good as linux's

Comment: I know, but ZFS is running natively on other platforms. While hardware support isn't the same as Linux, that should be the least of your worries.  ZFS is a full storage stack, so software raid is out of the equation. Evaluate how you're going to store, manage, protect,  and backup your data first before choosing your OS or storage system. Don't discount ZFS just because it's not native on Linux, it's probably the most advanced storage solution available for free right now.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, but I do not understand: **even if** I could use FreeBSD without problems (not so sure about it), is there anything like software raid implemented ? Anything like LUKS (Linux Encryption) for FreeBSD ? Thanks. I'm familiar with Gentoo and Debian GNU/Linux mostly. The server is a **home server**.

Comment: Or are you suggesting another operating system than FreeBSD ?

Comment: Open Solaris ;) with native ZFS

Comment: @tuergeist seems like OpenSolaris is not developed anymore since the acquisition of Sun Microsystem by Oracle corporation

Comment: @user51166: have a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/index.html but btw a default linux etx4 might be enough or do you really really need such big  partitions?

Comment: For future scalability I might want more than 20GB. I currently plan already to have 16GB partitions which is exactly the limit. Oracle's solaris is not opensource anyway. So wasn't Sun's anyway. Using EXT4 on my desktop and very happy with it. Too bad there's the 16GB limit. Anyway I'm more looking for a server grade filesystem at this point, therefore ... However the system management should be "easy" to handle: package manager and availability of open source software easily available. The basic idea behind linux was that I could setup TV / Media streaming with it as well as storage.

Comment: A separate Fileserver may be an option, although it shouldn't require much maintenance. What about hardware RAID ?

Comment: **Software** raid sorry, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alot of people are suggesting ZFS. But ZFS is not available natively under Linux except through fuse. I wouldn't recommend this for your situation where performance is likely to be important.

Unfortunately, ZFS will never be available as a native kernel module unless licencing issues are sorted out somehow.

XFS is good, but some people have reported corruption issues and I can't really comment on that.  I've played with small XFS partitions and not had these problems but not in production.

ZFS has too many advantages & useful features that cannot be ignored though.
In summary they are (see [ZFS Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) for a full description of what they mean):

- Data integrity
- Storage pools
- L2ARC
- High capacity
- Copy on write
- Snapshots & clones
- Dynamic striping
- Variable block sizes
- Lightweight filesystem creation
- Cache management
- Adaptive endianness
- Deduplication
- Encrypion

So how do we get around it? My suggested alternative which may suit your situation is to consider [nexenta](http://www.nexenta.org/).  This is an Open Solaris kernel with GNU userland tools running on top.  Having an Open Solaris kernel means having ZFS available natively.

Comment: From their site "Community Edition: Unlimited, FREE version for up to 18TB of storage". Seems like I'd get another limitation like EXT4's

Comment: And I understood that ZFS is simply the "best" as almost all of you are saying. Just trying to figure out the "best" operating system / solaris distribution able to run it.

Comment: Debian GNU/kFreeBSD seems to support ZFS and I like the Debian way, not sure I can use this however since there seems to be a small supporting community and still has some major bugs.

Comment: @user51166 - You should also consider FreeBSD or FreeNAS if your server is purely for storage.  Both have ZFS support.

Answer (score 4):

You should give a try to XFS, fit well in your requirements :

> XFS is a 64-bit file system. It supports a maximum file system size of
>   8 exbibytes minus  one byte, though this is subject to block limits
>   imposed by the host operating system.  On 32-bit Linux systems, this
>   limits the file and file system sizes to 16 tebibytes.

Comment: I heard it could cause data losses when facing power outages and its journaling doesn't cover data (only journal on metadata). Had used it once on my desktop but generated a lot of fsck errors, therefore I prefererred not to use it anymore. I repeat: performance is not the (main) scope of this choice: stability is.

Comment: I don't think that XFS is unstable, i  use it in several file servers and i I didn't have any problems ...

Comment: No, it's stable in the sense of having a stable version. Does that imply that I won't have data losses through the years ? XFS is surely good if you're looking for performance, though I remember reading on the net there were data loss issues (though not as many as with reiser 3 fortunately). Forgot to specify, but I'm looking at a LUKS setup, therefore **LVM will be used**, if that can help.

Comment: Doesn't not exist a perfect FileSystem... I think that for your requirements XFS is the best fit . There should not be any problem using LVM on XFS.

Comment: Surely not. Any special "restrictions" / "characteristics" ? Online fsck and / or defragmentation issues like ext4's issues ?

Comment: And mostly important resize: adding a disk to the array (RAID 6) and use the new available size (mdadm --grow). Is there something XFS specific I should know or all I need is LVM ?

Comment: Been using XFS ontop of a 12 HDD hardware RAID6 (ARECA PCIe RAID card with internal Battery Backup and external UPS, redundant Power Supply (one in wall, one in UPS)) from kernels 2.6 until recent. No problems so far, not a single file lost. All using different versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Your easiest option is to use XFS.  A lot of the bad experiences around XFS are based on old versions and desktop hardware problems that I don't think are really relevant for new deployments onto standard quality server hardware.  I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/en/2010/04/the-return-of-xfs-on-linux.html) about this subject that may help you sort out the current situation.  There are multiple busy XFS database installations with hundreds of users and terabytes of data I help manage.  They're all on the Debian Lenny kernel (2.6.26) or later and I haven't heard a hint of trouble with them in years.  I wouldn't use XFS with any earlier kernel than that.  I have heard some direct reports of people seeing strange XFS behavior still when the system runs out of memory or disk space; I haven't seen that myself yet though.

The only other reasonable option is to use ext4 with [some hacking](http://blog.ronnyegner-consulting.de/2011/08/18/ext4-and-the-16-tb-limit-now-solved/) to support larger filesystems.  I wouldn't expect that to have a very different reliability level.  I've had to recover data from multiple broken ext4 systems that ran into kernel bugs, so far ones all fixed upstream but not in the distributor's kernel at that time.  ext4 has its own set of metadata issues like [Delayed allocation data loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4#Delayed_allocation_and_potential_data_loss), things that were less likely to happen on ext3.  I would estimate the odds of you hitting an ext4 bug would be even higher than normal if you're forcing it over the normal size limit, simply because it seems more likely you'll be hitting a less well tested new code path at some point.

Alternative idea is to just use safer and boring ext3, accept the 16TB limit, and partition things better so no single filesystem has to be that large.

One loose end related to journal issues.  You didn't talk about how all these drives are going to be connected.  Make sure you understand the implication of any write caching that's in your storage chain here.  Either disable it or make sure the filesystem is flushing the cache out.  I've stashed some resources about that at [Reliable Writes](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Reliable_Writes) if that's not something you're checking yet.

Drives suck.  RAID arrays suck.  Filesystems suck.  Multiple failures happen.  I'm glad to see you're already thinking about backups; going from good to great reliability on storage requires more than just RAID and some spare drives.  Redundancy costs something at every level, and the money for hardware vs. software complexity one is tricky to navigate.  And watch your performance expectations.  While a RAID array like you're considering will easily do hundreds of MB/s, all it takes is two concurrent readers seeking the disk around constantly to drop that to only a few MB/s instead.  I can easily crush a 24 disk RAID10 array such that it only delivers <5MB/s against a [benchmark workload](https://github.com/gregs1104/seek-scaling).  One thing that helps there is to make sure you tweak readahead upward if multiple streaming readers are possible.

Comment: I'm going to use this at home, therefore I plan on using mainstream hardware. Might as well use server Hardware but I still have to see yet what SB-E is going to offer next year in the xeon department (I would've also liked to play a bit with virtualisation). If it's not too much expensive I plan going with cheap server hardware and ECC memory (lots of it). Performance-wise I don't want anything exceptional.

Comment: And yes, I'm thinking about backups, but still not have implemented them yet. I'm still looking for a backup solution capable of creating a system image and / or easily tar/zip/... required folders with a managament interface which allow automatic restores. BackupPC seems just a bittle limited and not sure I'd trust Crashplan (use it to backup data to remote location, would like redundancy therefore another system). Do I have to write a web GUI myself or something like this already exist (open source software, or at least free of charge to use)

Answer (score 2):

Deploying on ZFS using FreeBSD could happen here using [gbde](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/disks-encrypting.html) for encryption.  ZFS itself would be the software RAID provider, via [RAIDZ](http://blogs.oracle.com/bonwick/entry/raid_z).  The storage management complexity of building zpools is not significantly different than what Linux is going to put you through with mdadm, and in some cases will actually be easier.  My first ZFS install (on Solaris 10 about 3 years ago) had a 17TB filesystem over 48 drives.  I survived multiple failures there without a problem, learning ZFS management as I went.

The main upside is that [ZFS's checksumming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Data_Integrity) provides better error detection than Linux can, which is a defense against bad hardware worth considering.  Main downsides are around FreeBSD being less popular.  You don't know how to administer it yet, hardware support is a bit weaker than Linux, and since it's a less popular platform there aren't as many people to ask for help if you do run into issues.

A many terabyte storage array does really highlight what ZFS is good at though.  It's worth considering seriously if you are willing to take a plunge into something new.  If you want to explore true backup paranoia, build Linux and FreeBSD backup servers, to reduce the odds of OS bugs as a single point of failure cause.

Comment: Already have Linux as file server and I still have to really begin use it (I only began some tests of software RAID-6 + LUKS on 6 disks). Only problem is that I have very little time to play with it. I like your answer. So what do you suggest as operating system if going the ZFS way ? FreeBSD and opensolaris (not maintained anymore), OpenIndiana (OpenSolaris opensource as I've seen it) and Solaris Express 11 (Oracle :S) seem to be the only choices. I don't use this at work, its my hobby at home, but I would like something stable anyway and which is easy to use as well.

Comment: I've really grown used to use aptitude and emerge. My understanding in how you compile / manage / update ports in freebsd (cd /usr/... && make install) is that it just doesn't seem "right" (I hope the purist will forgive me for the use of this term, but it seems strange to me that if you want to update a package you have to do that, no automatic dependency resolving [I just took a small look at the FreeBSD's manual]). Or is there a simple package management system like debian's or gentoo's ?

Comment: I already know I could simply rsync what I want or tar/diff etc but I would like to know if anything more practical already exist. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the volume size limit, according to [Comparison of file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) there are many notable file systems that suit your needs such as JFS, XFS, UDF, ZFS, GPFS and Btrfs. You can click the *Maximum file size* and *Maximum volume size* columns to sort and see what suites your needs

But since your requirements not only include volume size but also reliability and scalability, you should check other capability tables in the same page. Currently the best ones for a large number of files as well as resiliency are ZFS and Btrfs. Both of them has been stable for a long time and can be used as the root file systems for many distros as of now. [OpenZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenZFS) has been founded in 2013 so no worry about ZFS in Linux